# linux shell : how to call programs after a while

Tags: linux, shell

when start virtual box if I remap my key, that key will not pass to virtualbox, so I must set the xkbmap to default us, then start vm, then wait a moment call xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap

```
setxkbmap us
VirtualBox --startvm XP &
#wait a moment
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

how to write this shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep #` where # is number of seconds to wait

```
setxkbmap us
VirtualBox --startvm XP &
#wait 5 seconds
sleep 5
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sleep:

```
sleep N
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to wait until the server is not started. You might be able to do below to find this out:

```
echo `VirtualBox status | grep started | wc -l`
```